# Assign value to Registered Hidden Field in page ClientScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am using Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("hf_Name",value) in an ASP.net application, how to override or assign a new value to the same Hidden Field 'hf_Name' in code behind?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use a `HiddenField` control?

Comment: because it's being changed by JS dynamically generated code,it's working fine using get and set in JS but i need to override its value from ASP.net, i can get the value using Request.Form("hf_Name") but how to assign a new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegisterHiddenField` doesn't create a server side control, it just
creates a plain-old `<input type="hidden" name="myhiddenField">`

`Page.FindControl("myhiddenField")` will never find anything on serverside and even `document.getElementById("myhiddenField")` will return nothing on clientside since only the name and not the id is assigned.

So if you need to access it on serverside, you should use a [`HiddenField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) server control or at least use a `html-input` `type=hidden` with `runat="server"`.

Comment: i can get the value using Request.Form("hf_Name"), but is it impossible to  assign a new value even by using JS?

Comment: in JS i can use : $get('hf_Name').value=newval; !!

Comment: @Ala: Yes, you can assign it via javascript but not from serverside code(apart from the initial value). But i don't understand why you don't want to declare it explicitely with `runat="server"`. Then you can access it easily from server- and clientside.

Comment: because it's dynamically generated and being changed by JS code, do you think it's better to generate ASP.net Hidden fields instead for this scenario?

Comment: @Ala: Is it dynamically created on server or via javascript? If it is the former, i would create HiddenField webcontrols instead. Then they are also part of the page's control collection and it's much easier to read or write them. You would for example get all hiddenfields on the page with just one line:  `var hiddens = Page.Controls.OfType<HiddenField>();`