# The value is not retained with Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hiddenfield, registerclientscriptblock, clientscript

In Asp.net c#, with this syntax:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("hfFileName", Value);
```

I can define a Hiddenfield:

1) Why in this code , the value is nothing:

```
function pageLoad() {     
alert(document.getElementById("hfFileName").getAttribute("value")); 
}
```

2) Whats the difference between this hiddenField and this one which I can define from Asp.net toolbox:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

Thank you in advanced.

> It was working before, I changed some code in Update panels and now
>   its not working, is it possible of that?

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10604340/795683

Comment: @SainPradeep Thanks , but "Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField" is working on the serverside, yes? and it set the value of a Hidden ClientSide Control . then why its not retain the value in $.ready()?

Comment: also it says I should use a HiddenField server control, then whats the usage of **Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField**?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

on Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("hfFileName", "testvalue");
        }
```

on Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            alert(document.getElementById("hfFileName").getAttribute("value"));
        })
```

This is working for me.

Comment: it works, but my problem is how can I set the value in page_Load. I dont have the calculated value

Comment: Please let me know where do you want to put your calculation logic in c# or in jQuery

Comment: its in a function in the first pageLoad(postback=false) , but page_load is fired twice and in second time, the value is not exists

Comment: Please give your complete snippet, because pageLoad() was firing for only time for me and producing correct value.